# Freeing memory of used data leads to Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable, resize

I wrote a hashtable and it basically consists of these two structures:

```
typedef struct dictEntry {
    void *key;
    void *value;
    struct dictEntry *next;
} dictEntry;

typedef struct dict {
    dictEntry **table;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long items;
} dict;
```

`dict.table` is a multidimensional array, which contains all the stored key/value pair, which again are a linked list.

If half of the hashtable is full, I expand it by doubling the size and rehashing it:

```
dict *_dictRehash(dict *d) {
    int i;
    dict *_d;
    dictEntry *dit;

    _d = dictCreate(d->size * 2);

    for (i = 0; i < d->size; i++) {
        for (dit = d->table[i]; dit != NULL; dit = dit->next) {
            _dictAddRaw(_d, dit);
        }
    }

    /* FIXME memory leak because the old dict can never be freed */
    free(d); // seg fault

    return _d;
}
```

The function above uses the pointers from the old hash table and stores it in the newly created one. When freeing the old `dict d` a Segmentation Fault occurs.

How am I able to free the old hashtable struct without having to allocate the memory for the key/value pairs again?

Edit, for completness:

```
dict *dictCreate(unsigned long size) {
    dict *d;

    d = malloc(sizeof(dict));
    d->size  = size;
    d->items = 0;
    d->table = calloc(size, sizeof(dictEntry*));

    return d;
}

void dictAdd(dict *d, void *key, void *value) {
    dictEntry *entry;

    entry = malloc(sizeof *entry);

    entry->key   = key;
    entry->value = value;
    entry->next  = '\0';

    if ((((float)d->items) / d->size) > 0.5) d = _dictRehash(d);

    _dictAddRaw(d, entry);
}

void _dictAddRaw(dict *d, dictEntry *entry) {
    int index = (hash(entry->key) & (d->size - 1));

    if (d->table[index]) {
        dictEntry *next, *prev;

        for (next = d->table[index]; next != NULL; next = next->next) {
            prev = next;

        }

        prev->next = entry;
    } else {
        d->table[index] = entry;
    }
    d->items++;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear; is your question "why do I get a seg-fault?"?

Comment: Using _underscores everywhere makes your code _very _hard _to _read.

Comment: Yes, actually, it is why do I get a seg fault! Will change asap.

Comment: What's dictCreate do, then? post the code ;-)

Answer (score 3):

1. best way to debug this is to run your code against valgrind .

But to you give some perspective :

1. when you `free(d)` you are expecting more of a `destructor` call on your `struct dict` which would internally free the memory allocated to the pointer to pointer to `dictEntry`
2. why do you have to delete the entire has table to expand it ? you have a `next` pointer anyways why not just append new hash entries to it ?

Solution is not to free the `d` rather just expand the `d` by allocating more `struct dictEntry` and assigning them to appropriate  `next`.

When contracting the `d` you will have to iterate over `next` to reach the end and then start freeing the memory for `struct dictEntry`s inside of your `d`.

Comment: Thank you, your first point is the solution.
Expanding the list isn't the wanted behaviour.

Comment: an up vote and accepting the answer would be nice if that resolves your issue :D

Comment: It's not quite solved yet. It's a memory leak if I can't free the old dict, right?
What solutions are there to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

To clarify Graham's point, you need to pay attention to how memory is being accessed in this library.  The user has one pointer to their dictionary.  When you rehash, you free the memory referenced by that pointer.  Although you allocated a new dictionary for them, the new pointer is never returned to them, so they don't know not to use the old one.  When they try to access their dictionary again, it's pointing to freed memory.

One possibility is not to throw away the old dictionary entirely, but only the dictEntry table you allocated within the dictionary.  That way your users will never have to update their pointer, but you can rescale the table to accomodate more efficient access.  Try something like this:

```
void _dictRehash(dict *d) {
    printf("rehashing!\n");
    int i;
    dictEntry *dit;

    int old_size = d->size;
    dictEntry** old_table = d->table;
    int size = old_size * 2;

    d->table = calloc(size, sizeof(dictEntry*));
    d->size = size;
    d->items = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {
        for (dit = old_table[i]; dit != NULL; dit = dit->next) {
            _dictAddRaw(d, dit);
        }
    }

    free(old_table);
    return;

}
```

---

As a side note, I'm not sure what your hash function does, but it seems to me that the line

```
int index = (hash(entry->key) & (d->size - 1));
```

is a little unorthodox.  You get a hash value and do a bitwise and with the size of the table, which I guess works in the sense that it will be guaranteed to be within (I think?) `[0, max_size)`, I think you might mean `%` for modulus.

Comment: That's pretty much right, I think  - but there's another issue: `_dictAddRaw` adds *the entire chain* of entries because the entry's `next` field is never set to NULL (and be careful where it's NULLed because you need it in the `for` loop. So the rebuilt table will be a mess of interlinked chains... Also the `& (size-1)` should work assuming the table size is always a power of 2. But modulus is much better!

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing a pointer which is passed in to your function. This is only safe if you know that whoever's calling your function isn't still trying to use the old value of `d`. Check all the code which calls `_dictRehash()` and make sure nothing's hanging on to the old pointer.

Comment: Hmmn, I call dictAdd(d, key, value), which checks if the hashtable is full and then calls _dictRehash(), could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, unless `dictAdd()` returns the new dict pointer to its caller.

Answer (score 1):

What does `dictCreate` actually do?

I think you're getting confused between the (fixed size) `dict` object, and the (presumably variable sized) array of pointers to `dictEntries` in `dict.table`.

Maybe you could just `realloc()` the memory pointed to by `dict.table`, rather than creating a new 'dict' object and freeing the old one (which incidentally, isn't freeing the table of dictentries anyway!)

Comment: I avoided realloc because it is supposed to be very slow. However, I am aware that the entries aren't freed - the pointers are just used again in the new hashtable.

Comment: That's called 'premature optimization. Anyhow, speed is the least of your worries at the moment.